# Redirect domain from specifiied incoming IP address

Tags: dns, ip-geolocation

I have 4 application servers who doing same task.
The servers located on certain branches.
Example :

- Server A : app1.something.com; 192.168.102.1; located on Country1
- Server B : app2.something.com; 192.168.102.2; located on Country2
- Server C : app3.something.com; 192.168.102.3; located on Country3
- Server D : app4.something.com; 192.168.102.4; located on Country4

Domain name of the application is app.something.com

Question :

- How the client on each country getting access to the application who located on their location with app.something.com domain?
- Does DNS server or router device to be configured in order to be accessed by client?
- If DNS Server to be configured, which record of zone that should be modified?

Comment: Is [Geodns](http://www.caraytech.com/geodns/) what you want?